# How does an OAuth2 server obtain launch context for smart on FHIR?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, hl7-fhir

I am integrating a Smart on FHIR app that will be launched from within an EHR.  When the user clicks a button to launch the app, we set a GUID and the current Patient ID to a database record on our FHIR server.  The assumption being that given the 'Launch' scope, the OAuth server will call the appropriate API to retrieve the Patient ID given that the GUID is included in the url params.

The call to auth looks like this:

```
_clientID = {the unique client ID registered to our auth server}
_redirectURL = {redirect back to auth for eventual token request}
launch={the GUID value generated at start of the session and paired with the Patient ID}
_scopes = "launch patient/*.* openid profile"
state = {some opaque value}
aud = {the base URL for our FHIR server}

string url = $"{authorizeURL}?response_type=code&client_id={_clientID}&" +
                $"redirect_uri={_redirectURL}&" +
                $"launch={launch}&" +
                $"scope={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_scopes)}&" +
                $"state={state}&" +
                $"aud=https://xxx-smart.xxxxxxxxx.com";
```

All of this works and I end up with a json response that includes the id_token, access_token, expires_in, token_type('Bearer').  But, no 'patient'.

My assumption was that the OAuth server would call the scope 'launch/patient' on our FHIR server but no such call is being made.  In fact, I created a few endpoints just for the purpose of logging and NONE of them are being called.

Here is an example of one of my FHIR Server test/log endpoints (I created few with 1 to 4 parameters):

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("{functionName}/{id}")]
    public string GetPatientData3(string functionName, string id)
    {
        TelemetryClient telemetry = new();
        telemetry.TrackEvent($"FHIR SVR GetPatientData3 {functionName} {id}");

        string configJson = "0009998888";
        return configJson;

    }
```

How do I set this 'patient' context properly?

How does the OAuth server retrieve this context so I can have that patient ID appear in the json response from the ~/token call?

**Further Notes:**

The contents of the openid-configuration:

```
{"token_endpoint":
    "https://aadproxy.azurewebsites.net/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token",
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": 
["client_secret_post","private_key_jwt","client_secret_basic"], 
"jwks_uri": 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/discovery/v2.0/keys",
"response_modes_supported": ["query","fragment","form_post"],
"subject_types_supported": ["pairwise"],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
"response_types_supported":["code","id_token","code 
id_token","id_token token"],
"scopes_supported":["openid","profile","email","offline_access"], 
"issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/v2.0",
"request_uri_parameter_supported":false, 
"userinfo_endpoint":"https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo", 
"authorization_endpoint": 
    "https://aadproxy.azurewebsites.net/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize", 
"device_authorization_endpoint": 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode",
"http_logout_supported":true,
"frontchannel_logout_supported":true,
"end_session_endpoint": 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
"claims_supported": 
    ["sub","iss","cloud_instance_name","cloud_instance_host_name", 
    "cloud_graph_host_name","msgraph_host","aud","exp","iat", 
    "auth_time","acr","nonce","preferred_username", 
    "name","tid","ver","at_hash","c_hash","email"],
"kerberos_endpoint": 
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/kerberos",
"tenant_region_scope":"NA",
"cloud_instance_name":"microsoftonline.com",
"cloud_graph_host_name":"graph.windows.net",
"msgraph_host":"graph.microsoft.com",
"rbac_url":"https://pas.windows.net"}
```

So, I notice that the 'patient/*.*' and the 'launch' scope among a whole host of others that I have are not supported according to my openid config.  The only supported ones are "openid","profile","email", "offline_access".

In Azure AD, 'App Registration' > 'Expose an API' I have a list of at least 15 scopes entered there.  In 'API' permissions they are all listed there as well.

One other thing to note, AzureAD does not handle scopes with a forward slash.  So, launch/patient has to be entered as launch-patient.  We also had to implement a proxy server to capture the ~/oauth2/v2.0/authorize request and modify the scope parameter entries to reflect this before passing on the request to the actual server.

I guess the pertinent question now is: How do the scopes that I have entered manually get supported?

Comment: I'm wondering if your 'scope' parameter is incorrect. Is the server following SMART 2.0? If so, /*.* should be /*.cruds instead. When you call ~/.well-known/smart-configuration for the FHIR server, what are the listed 'scopes_supported'?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are on to something.  The vendor we are working with support both OpenID and Smart.  We chose to go with OpenID as it is more out of the box but it looks like we need more aspects of the Smart implementation anyway.  I've posted the contents of our openid-configuration and indeed it looks like most if not all of the scopes I have entered in our server do not show up there.